# unable to create SCCS file

Tags: ubuntu, version-control

I am working on Ubuntu13.04.
I created a file named quit.c
I am trying check-in this file in to its SCCS file, s.quit.c
I am creating the SCCS file as below using `admin` command:

```
ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:~/CCPP/HelloWorld/das/das1/sccs$ admin -i quit.c s.quit.c
admin: quit.c is an invalid name.  SCCS file names must begin `s.'

admin: The 'i' keyletter can't be used with multiple files.
ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:~/CCPP/HelloWorld/das/das1/sccs$
```

I think the syntax has changed from what it was earlier. Is it so?
How to create the SCCS file for check-in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not have a SCCS file yet for `quit.c` you have to

```
mkdir SCCS
sccs create quit.c
```

that will create `s.quit.c` in SCCS

You can the edit with `sccs edit quit.c` and commit with `sccs delta quit.c`.

You should be ablte to try this by cut-and-pasting:

```
mkdir sccs_test
cd sccs_test
echo 'hallo' > quit.c
mkdir SCCS
sccs create quit.c
sccs edit quit.c
echo 'bye' >> quit.c
sccs delta quit.c
```

The last command asks for a comment input.

Comment: No, it couldn't create the SCCS file. I got the following error:
`quit.c:
admin: SCCS/z.quit.c: Can't create lock file : No such file or directory`

Comment: I just tried again. I'm using `sccs` from the `cssc` package on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Comment: I had installed the same package `cssc` but why that error!! I checked under sccs subdirectory and it's not there.

Comment: You have to create `SCCS` not `sccs`

Comment: yes you are right. It's working fine. Thanks a lot! But do you have any idea why the `admin` command I mentioned in my Q doesn't work. Because this way is mentioned in a book which I'm following. Is it that the syntax/format is changed. It seems so as the book is 7 yrs old.

Comment: Well [cssc](http://www.gnu.org/software/cssc/) is not sccs, so there are bound to be differences some parts.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11548/discussion-between-ravi-and-zelda)

Comment: May you please come on chat by clicking the above link. There you may need to login by clicking the link at bottom of the page

Comment: chat login doesn't work for me (No referer was present..) but yes AFAIK sccs edit is an editable version of `get`. Have you considered something more modern than sccs? `rcs` is as simple, but better with many revisions. And there is much more modern change management with mercurial (`hg`).

Comment: Why don't you use the real SCCS? Check http://sccs.sf.net and prefer the more recent versions in `schilytools`. The real SCCS is feature  complete...and much faster than the CSSC clone

Answer (score 0):

You are not using `SCCS`, but something else... the `SCCS` program `admin` gives different error messages than what you report. Leẗ́s see:

```
admin -i quit.c s.quit.c
ERROR: more than one file (ad15)

ad15:
"more than one file"
You are trying to create more than one SCCS file, and you supplied
the 'i' keyletter. You can only create one file when you supply
the 'i' keyletter.
```

You made a simple mistake and inserted a space between the -i and it's argument. As a reaction on your problem, I just enhanced the help text
for this problem, so the new help text is:

```
ad15:
"more than one file"
You are trying to create more than one SCCS file, and you supplied
the 'i' keyletter. You can only create one file when you supply
the 'i' keyletter. A possible reason for the problem is that you
have a space between the 'i' keyletter and the input filename.
```

See the `POSIX` man page for `admin`:

> -i[name]
>
> Specify the name of a file from which the text for a new SCCS file shall be taken. The text constitutes the first delta of the file (see
>   the -r option for the delta numbering scheme). If the -i option is
>   used, but the name option-argument is omitted, the text shall be
>   obtained by reading the standard input. If this option is omitted, the
>   SCCS file shall be created with control information but without any
>   file data. The -i option implies the -n option.

and the original `admin` man page http://sccs.sourceforge.net/man/sccs-admin.1.html

```
-i[filename]
  Initializes  the  history file with text from the indicated file.
  This text constitutes the initial delta, or set of checked-in
  changes.  If filename is omitted, the initial text is obtained
  from the standard input.  Omitting  the  -i option  altogether
  creates an empty s.file.  You can only initialize one s.file
  with text using -i unless you use the bulk option -N.  The 
  -i option implies the -n option.
```

In general, it is recommended not to use the `SCCS` low level commands directoy but via the `sccs` frontend. So please just call:

```
sccs create quit.c
```

This will automatically create a directory `SCCS` if needed and place the new file `s.quit.c` into that directory.

BTW: gegeral information about the `SCCS` software is at: http://sccs.sf.net and up to date sources are part of the `schilytools` package at: http://sourceforge.net/projects/schilytools/files/

Comment: @stackexchange please do something against the downvoting trolls that are stalking me. This is  course is a usefule answer as (in contrary to the other answer) explains why the problem occured.